# latex manual insert some special figure name in the list of figure

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

When I use `\section*{namename}`, if I want to insert it in the toc, I will use `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{namename}`

So, I want to know, if I want insert some figure name (I don't use `\caption{}` for some special figure) in the list of figure, what command should be using?

Is there some way just like use `addcontentsline`???

Comment: try `\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{namename}`

Answer (score 1):

The `\caption` does not have a `*`-version, so you would have to make it.

Furthermore, you'd have to replicate `\addcontentsline` to behave like `\caption` does.

This is one way to implement the `\addcontentsline` for `\listoffigures`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\addtoLOF[1]{\refstepcounter\@captype%
    \addcontentsline{\csname ext@figure\endcsname}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\csname thefigure\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #1}}
}
\makeatother
```

Further, here is also an implementation of a starred version of caption:

This is one way to do that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% Redefine @caption
\let\original@caption\caption%
\let\original@@caption\@caption%
\long\def\@caption@star#1[#2]#3{%
    \par
    \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
        \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
    \endgroup}
% Make a starred version of \caption
\long\def\caption{\@ifstar{\let\@caption\@caption@star\original@caption}{\let\@caption\original@@caption\original@caption}}
% If you don't care about the star thing, the command below is all you need:
\newcommand\addtoLOF[1]{\refstepcounter\@captype%
    \addcontentsline{\csname ext@figure\endcsname}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\csname thefigure\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #1}}
}
\begin{document}
    \listoffigures\clearpage
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \Huge{A}
        \addtoLOF{Not caption}
        \caption*{test}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: Fixed recursion.